# Running mysql commands inside bash script

Tags: mysql, bash, command-line, command

I am trying to  execute a mysql command inside a bash script but every time I try to execute it fails for some reason. I have tried several ways and none seemed to work(e.g: <<QUERY...;QUERY)
My select is the following but I get an error:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -utesting -pMypass -hlocalhost -D test DB -e "

SELECT value FROM h6_options

where module=cloud

AND `option`=prefix;"

I get the following error.
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 3: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '='prefix'' at line 5

Any help is appreciated.
```

Comment: just a silly question here...is prefix a variable?  or a string value? if a string value, shouldn't it be `'prefix'`?  Thanks.

Comment: it is string I tried  that and I get this error: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 3: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '='prefix'' at line 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was the backticks. I had to escape them in order to not evaluate the line.

```
<<QUERY
SELECT value FROM h6_options

WHERE \`option\`="prefix"

AND module="cloud"
QUERY
```

Comment: there you go.  awesome....this was a good one.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a multi-line SQL statement.  this means you have two options:

1. you can push everything into one single line.
2. try reformatting your script to use `EOF` tags instead.
3. any option I didn't think of that the smart people here can consider...

here's an example:

```
mysql -u USER -pPASSWORD <<EOF
SQL_QUERY 1
SQL_QUERY 2
SQL_QUERY N
EOF
```

so for you, I would do this:

```
mysql -utesting -pMypass -hlocalhost -D test DB <<EOF
SELECT value FROM h6_options
where module=cloud
AND `option`='prefix';
EOF
```

Note: I don't like using the word EOF....for me, I like the word SQL or QUERY.  because EOF means end of file.  The code is identical, so you can use the word of choice:

```
mysql -utesting -pMypass -hlocalhost -D test DB <<QUERY
SELECT `value` FROM `h6_options`
where `module`='cloud'
AND `option`='prefix';
QUERY
```

Source:  https://www.shellhacks.com/mysql-run-query-bash-script-linux-command-line/

Comment: that solved the first error, but now I get this:
mysql: option '-e' requires an argument
./s3_clone.sh: line 3: SELECT: command not found
./s3_clone.sh: line 4: where: command not found
./s3_clone.sh: line 5: option: command not found
./s3_clone.sh: line 5: AND: command not found
./s3_clone.sh: line 6: QUERY: command not found

Comment: ditch the -e and see what that gives you...

Comment: Syntax to use near 'QUERY' at line 1
./s3_clone.sh: line 3: SELECT: command not found
./s3_clone.sh: line 4: WHERE: command not found
./s3_clone.sh: line 5: option: command not found
./s3_clone.sh: line 5: AND: command not found
./s3_clone.sh: line 6: QUERY: command not found

Comment: my bad.  only 2 <<'s are needed.  sorry, I did it in my head first. :)...editing my answer.

Comment: ok.  ditch the `-e` and only use 2 x `<<` in the line.  try that.

Comment: of note, this solution (when I get it right) can handle multiple statements.  you can treat the space between `<<query` and `query` as an open area for 1 or more statements.

Comment: with 2 <<  it goes back  to the initial error. ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '='prefix'' at line 3

Comment: just for stupidity, have you tested teh query in a mysql ide?

Comment: tested in the client using the following: SELECT value FROM h6_options
WHERE module='cloud'
AND `option`='prefix'
and it returned results. It is slightly different(removed the ticks from value). but in the sh script still fails.

Comment: what's the new error?

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '='prefix'' at line 3

Comment: wait.  remove ticks from the value....is prefix a variable?  are you using prefix to inject values for your query to go afteR?

Comment: prefix is not a variable, it is string